# how to make server/client to accept more the one input in (c#/java)

Tags: c#, java

This is the code on the server (C#) :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread service = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, 13235);
            listener.Start();
            Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            NetworkStream str = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytes5 = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];


            str.Read(bytes5, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes5);

            Console.WriteLine("ewwww hone :" + returndata);
            label1.Text = returndata;
            client.Close();

        });
        service.Start();

    }

}
```

Client side on Java :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    DataInputStream is = null;
    int port = 13235;

    System.out.println("SocketClient initialized \n");
    try {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

        Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);
        os = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        os.writeBytes(jTextField1.getText()); 

        System.out.println(jTextField1.getText());
    }
    catch (IOException f) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + f);
    }
    catch (Exception g) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + g);
    }
}
```

My program works fine only the first time I click on the button, but after that I don't get anything!! Any idea how to fix it, or what's wrong? What I need is as much as I clicked on that button(in client side) I need to get it on server side ...

Comment: Give a little more background, specify what "The Button" is for example or what your program does.

Comment: @Leo Izen button is on cliend side : i need when a client click on this button .. its should get the text from a textbox then send this text to server side .. the problem here that its sending only one time and never send then until i close server side

Comment: @jolyTimePopCorn You should not ignore the result returned from [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the example code for `TcpListener` on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

You are missing the `while` loop in your code. After the first connection, it calls `.close()` then exits your thread. It should loop back to start listening for the next connection.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not closing the connection/stream and on the second click you are again opening a socket connection. You can either close the socket connection each time you get the click. Or you keep the socket open and do not reinitialize it every time a click happens.

Comment: i correct it ... but still not working .. ! i guess its a problem on the server side .. !

Comment: Can you share the corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your reading and writing stream code  within a `while loop` to read/write multiple times.